# Space in element attribute in xpath

Tags: xpath, yaml

We have this XPath defined in a YML file:

```
message_form_show: //div[@class='cart']/div[@class='message']/form[@id='message-form' and not contains(@style, 'display:none')]
```

However we'd like to change to '`display: none`' instead, but when adding the space, Netbeans complains saying the YML is not parsed correctly and running the Selenium test also fails on it.

Any ideas how this could be addressed?

Comment: The Selenium test fails on what? If it says that the element can't be found and the original element has no space in its `display:none`, then the XPath won't find it. Or does it fail on unparsable XPath exception?

Comment: It fails on an unparsable XPath exception

Comment: And if you tried to print out the XPath in the Selenium test, would it print the whole XPath? Or would it print some bogus?

Comment: Ohhhh, I see. The space after `display:` makes `display: ` seem like a yaml costruct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that after the change, [YAML parses](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#%3a%20mapping%20value//) `display:` (with colon followed by a space) as a new array which contains `none')]`. This usually enables YAML to contain e.g. lists of arrays of arrays, but in this situation, it makes things go wrong.

[The solution is to specifically delimit the string as a block so YAML won't try to resolve it](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2760844):

```
message_form_show: >
  //div[@class='cart']/div[@class='message']/form[@id='message-form' and not contains(@style, 'display: none')]
```

or just quote it with double quotes:

```
message_form_show: "//div[@class='cart']/div[@class='message']/form[@id='message-form' and not contains(@style, 'display: none')]"
```